# Can't connect to remote Xen libvirt with ssh, using virsh or virt-manager

Tags: debian, xen, debian-squeeze, libvirt, virt-manager

I'm running Xen 4 on a Debian server running Squeeze (stable). I want to connect remotely over ssh using virt-manager or virsh, because I can do that on a Lenny server (oldstable).

Xen is installed correctly, booted, I can do # xm list and see which domU are booted.
Libvirt-bin is installed, and running, with /etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf changed as following

```
listen_tls = 0
listen_tcp = 1
tcp_port = "8000"
listen_addr = "127.0.0.1"
```

netstat -tpln confirms that libvirtd listens to 127.0.0.1:8000

If i try to connect with virt-manager or virsh I don't have any error, just the connection hangs and never terminates...

Do you have any idea what can be the problem? I have tried on 2 different squeeze servers and never get it working.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here [Unable to connect Xend with virt-manager](https://serverfault.com/questions/259887/unable-to-connect-xend-with-virt-manager/326042#326042): I need to enable xend-unix-server in /etc/xen/xend-config.sxp

```
(xend-unix-server yes)
```

I add this to my original question (instead of deleting it) in case someone needs it.

Answer (score 1):

For me the trouble was not having

```
libvirtd_opts="-dl"
```

in the config file `/etc/default/libvirt-bin`.

so the daemon was not listening.

Answer (score 0):

For me the trouble was not having

```
listen_tcp = 1
```

in the config file

```
/etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf
```

I added this and after I've issued

```
sudo invoke-rc.d libvirt-bin restart
```